# ¿ Como podria hacer esta consulta con mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, mongoose

Hola soy nuevo en esto de las consultas usando mongoose.js para nodejs, no se si me puede colaborar pues en el query puedo mandar el campo del _id de la consulta a buscar pero no se como llegar a ella.

Anexo foto de la estructura a consultar resaltado con amarillo el id con el que quiero buscarlo. de ante mano agradezco su colaboración

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

//controller

```
PacienteController.encontrarConsulta = async (req, res) => {
const querys = await Paciente.find({ consulta:{ "$in" : [req.body.id]} });
console.log(querys);
}
```

//Modelo

```
const personalSchema = new Schema({
//tipado de datos y validaciones
nombres: {
    type: String,
},
apellidos: {
    type: String,
},
tipo_documento: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: TipoDocumento
},
entidad: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: Entidad
},
numero_documento: {
    type: Number,
},
email: {
    type: String,
    trim: true,
    lowercase: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
},
foto: {
    type: String,
},
telefono: {
    type: Number,
},
direccion: {
    type: String,
},
fecha_nacimiento: {
    type: Date,
},
cargo: {
    type: String
},
registro_medico: {
    type: String
},
firma: {
    type: String
},
genero: {
    type: String,
},
estado: {
    type: Number
},
roles: [{
    type: String
}],
permisos: [{
    type: String
}]
```

}, {
    timestamps: true,
    strict: false 
});

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama la colección? ¿Puedes agregar el controlador de express.js y mongoose?

Comment: Te invito a leer [ask] y [mcve]. Tu pregunta es muy amplia, y sin código para poder apreciar lo que intentas será difícil ayudarte. Por favor edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit] y agrega lo necesario. Saludos

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob ya añadi el modelo y el controlador

Answer (score 1):

Ya pude encontrar como hacer lo que necesitaba, para consultar una en especifica que esta almacenada dentro de otra colección

```
const querys = await Paciente.find({ 'consulta._id' : req.params.id }, {"consulta.$": 1});
```